# Shared Jenkins pipeline for Terraform

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, terraform

I am pretty new working with Jenkins and I have a couple of questions. I'm hoping you awesome guys can help guide me in the right direction. I have run out of google links and the Jenkins documentation isn't helping me here.

First a little info on what I'm working on. I am working on building a generic/shared Jenkins pipeline where our team can run our terraform code through. The pipeline is declarative with several stages: git checkout, TF init/plan, TF plan approval, and TF apply.

The three main issues I'm working through is:

1) Making sure there aren't any collisions as there will be quite a few people using this pipeline to deploy their terraform code. Right now, I am using three parameters on the workspace to help keep things containerized. Those are Project Name, Account Id, and Branch Name. I am also adding those parameters to the plan name for added comfort, but not sure if it's needed.

2) Putting Terraform Plan and Apply on different stages. When the apply runs, I get an error that I need to reinitialize when I did it in the previous stage. Is there something I'm missing to get this to work?

3) I am stashing and unstashing files between stages. Could this cause collisions when multiple people are using it? Or are the stages pretty containerized?

Here's the code: (the approval stage isn't there yet)

```
def repositoryURL = env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl != null && env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl != "" ? env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl : env.RepoURL
def repositoryBranch = env.gitlabTargetBranch != null && env.gitlabTargetBranch != "" ? env.gitlabTargetBranch : env.RepoBranch
def notificationEmail = env.gitlabUserEmail != null && env.gitlabUserEmail != "" ? env.gitlabSourceRepoHttpUrl : env.Email
def projectName = env.ProjectName
def deployAccountId = env.AccountId

pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage("Checkout") {
            agent any
            steps {
                git branch: "${repositoryBranch}", credentialsId: '...', url: "${repositoryURL}"
                stash name: 'tf', useDefaultExcludes: false
            }
        }
        stage("Terraform Plan") {
            agent {
                kubernetes {
                    label 'myagent'
                    containerTemplate {
                        name 'cis'
                        image 'docker-local.myrepo.com/my-image:v2'
                        ttyEnabled true
                        command 'cat'
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                container('cis') {                    
                    unstash 'tf'
                    script {                                                      
                        sh "terraform init"

                        try {
                            sh "terraform workspace select ${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}"
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            sh "terraform workspace new ${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}"
                        }

                        sh "terraform plan -out=${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}_plan.tfplan -input=false"

                        stash includes: "*.tfplan" name: "tf-plan", useDefaultExcludes: false
                    }
                }
            }
            post{
                success{
                    echo "Terraform init complete"
                }
                failure{
                    echo "Terraform init failed"
                }
            }
        }
        stage ("Terraform Apply") {
            agent {
                kubernetes {
                    label 'myagent'
                    containerTemplate {
                        name 'cis'
                        image 'docker-local.myrepo.com/my-image:v2'
                        ttyEnabled true
                        command 'cat'
                    }
                }
            }
            steps {
                container("cis") {
                    withCredentials([[
                        $class: 'AmazonWebServicesCredentialsBinding',
                        credentialsId: 'my-creds',
                        accessKeyVariable: 'AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
                        secretKeyVariable: 'AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
                    ]]) {
                        script {
                            unstash "tf"
                            unstash "tf-plan"                        
                            sh """
                               set +x
                               temp_role="\$(aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::000000000000:role/myrole --role-session-name jenkinzassume)" > /dev/null 2>&1

                               export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=\$(echo \$temp_role | jq .Credentials.AccessKeyId | xargs) > /dev/null 2>&1
                                export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=\$(echo \$temp_role | jq .Credentials.SecretAccessKey | xargs) > /dev/null 2>&1
                                export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=\$(echo \$temp_role | jq .Credentials.SessionToken | xargs) > /dev/null 2>&1
                                set -x

                               terraform apply ${deployAccountId}_${projectName}_${repositoryBranch}_plan.tfplan
                           """
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a broad question so I will leave a concise comment: 1. Jenkins Pipeline and/or TF collisions can be mitigated with a remote state backend. 2. This is because you really should look into using a plugin directory with TF init and then bind volume mounting that with your Jenkins container agents (applies the same to the k8s). 3. unsure 4. Consider replacing your global variables (at the top) with build parameters. 5. Would also recommend passing your creds to the apply instead of shell exporting them as the environment.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Thanks for your comment. Do you have any resources / examples I can check out for your answer on #2? As for #4) The global variables are conditionals based on whether the pipeline is run via gitlab commit hook or run manually with build parameters.